# Is it ok to scale labeled/binary data for principal component analysis (pca)?

Tags: scaling, pca, feature-extraction

I have a dataset which have about 20 columns of labeled data (numbered with `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`), 140 binary column (0 and 1) and 3 columns of numerical values. There are about 4400 rows in this dataset and I had a hard time to train a deep neural network on this dataset so I decided to reduce the features and remove unnecessary ones.

So here is what I did: I scaled those 3 columns and did the PCA with `sklearn.decomposition.PCA()` but the result was 99.7% on pca1 and 0.3% on pca2 and other pcas were 0.

Then for some random reason, I tried to scale the whole dataset:

```
df = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(df)
```

And tried PCA again and this time, the result was a bit more promising (but not perfect I guess). here are the pcas:

```
>>> print(np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_ * 100, decimals=1))
[2.7 2.1 1.8 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1 1.1 1.  1.  0.9 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7
 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.5
 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.2 0.2
 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is it allowed to scale data in such manners? (scaling labeled/binary data)
2. If yes, is such PCA useful for feature extraction? (since the best pca is 2.7%)

P.S. I'm pretty new to these stuffs. If I need to provide any other information, please let me know.